# Not able to align text fields in flutter using expanded and flex

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a desktop app.

I need to align the text filed on the left at the same time the net weight text area on the right has too much space. Also first weight textfiled needs to be aligned with Net weight which is on the right. Also the space if off when i change form max screen desktop view to minimum desktop view.

I tried to change expanded and flex but not able to align the text fields. Am I using the right widget or properties?

**Full screen view:**

[image]

**Minimum view**:

[image]

```
    body: Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                // color: Colors.indigo,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                height: 50,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Field 1',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Expanded(
              flex: 6, child: Container(color: Colors.teal, height: 50)),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 0),
                // color: Colors.amber,
                height: 50,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'First Weight',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                // color: Colors.indigo,
                height: 50,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Weight',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Expanded(
              flex: 5, child: Container(color: Colors.teal, height: 100)),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              width: 1000,
              height: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Text("Net Weight:",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)))
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      height: 10,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    Text("Second Weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                    Text("   :"),
                    Text("  100"),
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      height: 10,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    Text("First Weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                    Text("         :"),
                    Text("  60"),
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      height: 10,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    Text("Net Weight:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                    Text("         :"),
                    Text("  40"),
                  ])
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ])
```

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I have updated the description little more

Answer (score 0):

For the top Row, the summation flex value is 6, where bottom row is having 7. You need to replace use  last Expanded `flex:1`.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              // color: Colors.indigo,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              height: 50,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Field 1',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            )),
        Expanded(flex: 5, child: Container(color: Colors.teal, height: 50)),
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 0),
              // color: Colors.amber,
              height: 50,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'First Weight',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ],
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
            // color: Colors.indigo,
            height: 50,
            child: const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Weight',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.teal, height: 100)),
              Container(
                // width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Net Weight:",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        height: 10,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Text("Second Weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      Text("   :"),
                      Text("  100"),
                    ]),
                    Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        height: 10,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Text("First Weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      Text("         :"),
                      Text("  60"),
                    ]),
                    Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        height: 10,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Text("Net Weight:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      Text("         :"),
                      Text("  40"),
                    ])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        //right padding
        SizedBox(width: 40),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: thanks is is helpfull but the window shrinks the left side overflows. Is there a way for only the center bar teal color to shrink on resize but the lenght/ width of the textfields and the Netweight container on the left remain the same.

Comment: You can use another Row with flex:6.  updated